# NOT EXISTS não funciona como deveria

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, tabela-banco-de-dados

estou tentando fazer uma Query para uns processos internos, porém a validação principal não está funcionando. Tenho que trazer todos os "NUNOTA" em que os "CODSTATUS" sejam diferentes de 3, porém ele simplesmente não me retorna nada. E deveria me retornar um valor somente (que foi o que coloquei para teste na minha base).

Resumindo, se tiver três "NUNOTA" igual a 4 e um "NUNOTA" igual a 3, ele não traz nada.

Meu código:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
        TEMP.NUNOTA, 
        TEMP.AD_NUMINNO, 
        TEMP.CODPARC, 
        TEMP.CODPROD, 
        TEMP.CODSTATUS,
        TEMP.LNKLAYOUT,
        CTT.EMAIL AS EMAILCLIENTE,
        CTT.FAX,
        CTT.NOMECONTATO
        FROM AD_TEMPOLAYOUT AS TEMP
        INNER JOIN TGFCTT AS CTT ON TEMP.CODPARC = CTT.CODPARC
        INNER JOIN TGFCAB AS CAB ON TEMP.CODPARC = CAB.CODPARC
                                     AND CAB.CODCONTATO  = CTT.CODCONTATO
                                     AND TEMP.AD_NUMINNO = CAB.AD_NUMINNO
                                     AND TEMP.NUNOTA    = CAB.NUNOTA
        INNER JOIN TGFVEN AS VEN ON CAB.CODVEND          = VEN.CODVEND
        WHERE TEMP.LNKLAYOUT <> ''
        AND TEMP.CODSTATUS = '4'
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 NUNOTA FROM AD_TEMPOLAYOUT WHERE CODSTATUS = '3')   
        GROUP BY 
        TEMP.NUNOTA, 
        TEMP.AD_NUMINNO, 
        TEMP.CODPARC, 
        TEMP.CODPROD, 
        TEMP.CODSTATUS, 
        TEMP.LNKLAYOUT,
        CTT.EMAIL,
        CTT.FAX,
        CTT.NOMECONTATO
        ORDER BY TEMP.NUNOTA DESC
```

Comment: *"Tenho que trazer todos os "NUNOTA" em que os "CODSTATUS" sejam diferentes de 3"* sem um exemplo de dados é difícil ajudar mas... essa query funciona isolada ? `SELECT TOP 1 NUNOTA FROM AD_TEMPOLAYOUT WHERE CODSTATUS = '3'` ela me parece "sem sentido" ai solta sem relação com outra tabela na query, mas de novo, sem dados fica difícil... *"se tiver três "NUNOTA" igual a 4 e um "NUNOTA" igual a 3, ele não traz nada"* isso quer dizer o status? pq ser for deveria incluir os 3 e 4 no `WHERE`.  Adicione tbm na pergunta o SGBD que está suando, `sql-server` por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

A sua query não vai retornar nada se existir qualquer linha na tabela AD_TEMPOLAYOUT com o CODSTATUS igual a 3 pois essa é a única condição existente na query do Exists, sendo que para verificar somente as linhas com o mesmo NUNOTA é necessário adicionar uma condição nessa query do Exists:

```
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT NUNOTA FROM AD_TEMPOLAYOUT AS SUB
          WHERE SUB.NUNOTA = TEMP.NUNOTA AND SUB.CODSTATUS = '3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você deve retirar "NUNOTA" da linha
( SELECT TOP 1 NUNOTA FROM AD_TEMPOLAYOUT WHERE CODSTATUS = '3')

Comment: Ele continua não trazendo resultado...

Answer (score -1):

E se você tentar filtrar apenas por CODSTATUS <> '3' ?

```
SELECT TOP 10 
        TEMP.NUNOTA, 
        TEMP.AD_NUMINNO, 
        TEMP.CODPARC, 
        TEMP.CODPROD, 
        TEMP.CODSTATUS,
        TEMP.LNKLAYOUT,
        CTT.EMAIL AS EMAILCLIENTE,
        CTT.FAX,
        CTT.NOMECONTATO
        FROM AD_TEMPOLAYOUT AS TEMP
        INNER JOIN TGFCTT AS CTT ON TEMP.CODPARC = CTT.CODPARC
        INNER JOIN TGFCAB AS CAB ON TEMP.CODPARC = CAB.CODPARC
                                     AND CAB.CODCONTATO  = CTT.CODCONTATO
                                     AND TEMP.AD_NUMINNO = CAB.AD_NUMINNO
                                     AND TEMP.NUNOTA    = CAB.NUNOTA
        INNER JOIN TGFVEN AS VEN ON CAB.CODVEND          = VEN.CODVEND
        WHERE TEMP.LNKLAYOUT <> ''
        AND TEMP.CODSTATUS <> '3'
        GROUP BY 
        TEMP.NUNOTA, 
        TEMP.AD_NUMINNO, 
        TEMP.CODPARC, 
        TEMP.CODPROD, 
        TEMP.CODSTATUS, 
        TEMP.LNKLAYOUT,
        CTT.EMAIL,
        CTT.FAX,
        CTT.NOMECONTATO
        ORDER BY TEMP.NUNOTA DESC
```

Comment: Continua sem trazer resultados também, sendo que tem CODSTATUS = 4

Comment: Ah OK, então utilize LEFT JOIN e veja se retorna.